# Incidence of cap and trade

Tags: microeconomics, environmental-economics

Is there a way to show the incidence of cap and trade in a diagram? Similar to how in an indirect tax graph you can show consumer and producer incidence. I assume that the consumer incidence of cap and trade will be greater if the demand curve is inelastic.

[image: Tax Incidence Diagram]

[image: Cap and Trade Diagram]

This is like my cap and trade diagram. It's the market for the product not the market for permits.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition looks correct.

Yes, in the diagram you propose, a more inelastic demand would have a higher slope, making the price go up more.